# jQuery each and keyup

Tags: jquery

I have several fields on my page all have the same class of say "EntryField".

On the keypress within (any) of these fields I need to itterate through all fields with the class of EntryField.

Can I combine .each on a .keyup or do I need to bind keyup and then within the function of that do an each over the class EntryField?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind keyup an then within the function of that do an each on the class entry field.

```
$('.EntryField').keyup(function() {
    $('.EntryField').each(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
 });
```

Comment: +1 right, so this is what i'm asking.  can i do away with the selector and combine?  i suspect i cannot but thought i'd ask anyway

Comment: @griegs, AFAIK, you can not. You want to reference the result of $('.EntryField') but it's outside the scope of the anonymous handler function, so no.

Comment: yeah i kinda figured as much.  sometimes you just need somone else to confirm it for you so you don't waste more time.  cheers @Phil

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready( function() {

    jQuery('#add_address_button').click(function(){

        jQuery( "input[name*='locations']" ).each(function( index, element ) {
            jQuery("input[id*='locations']").keyup(function() {


            });
        });
    });
```